# Make link clickable through transparent overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a site that has horizontal parallax scrolling.  The site has a transparent layer to help the site scroll when you roll the mouse wheel.  There are a few clickable elements that use jquery that pass through this layer.  One section has simple links to external pages but for some reason the links are being blocked.  Pointer-events won't work because that will disable the scrolling.

I tried a simple click function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.link').click(function (event) {
     $(this).find('a').click();
 });
```

Is there a jquery script or something that will help the links pass through the top layer to be clickable?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: please give your code fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by stop uper layers `events`. Use below `css` for your transparent overlay.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: I've tried that.  That will stop the scrolling of the top layer.  I need to be able to click on the links and still maintain scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions but I solved the issue.  I put a click action on the li.  It still wasn't working but when I wrapped it in a span, it worked.  Go figure it would be something simple.